# Unpivot csv in NiFi and ingest it in sql server

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I am new to NiFi. Trying to ingest a csv file to sql server but need to unpivot the data before ingestion.
For example:
This is the original csv

```
Name, Maths, Science, English
Raghav, 60, 70, 80
Nisha, 77, 56, 89
```

Final output for sql table:

```
Name, subject, marks
Raghav, Maths, 60
Raghav, Science, 70
Raghav, English, 80
Nisha, Maths, 77
Nisha, Science, 56
Nisha, English, 89
```

How can I achieve this in NiFi. Without the need of a temp table

I tried using pandas but it is not supported in NiFi

Answer (score 3):

Apache NiFi can perform this operation but you will need to write custom logic and use an `ExecuteScript` processor.

This process is not generic & repeatable, because from the data provided, you do not know the "column" types in order to provide the new column names in the output. You will have to hardcode those values or read them in from a separate data source.

There are many examples of using Groovy/Ruby/Python or another scripting language to perform a *transpose* operation, which is what you want to do here. In Groovy, it is a method on a `List` of `List` objects, as defined in [List#transpose()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.10/html/api/groovy/util/GroovyCollections.html#transpose-java.util.List-). You can use simple Groovy CSV processing to load the CSV data into objects and call that method. Matt Burgess has provided a number of examples [using the `ExecuteScript` processor](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/02/invokescriptedprocessor-hello-world.html) to read in data from a flowfile, operate on it, and write it back to flowfile content and send it on to a subsequent connection.